# dual list box and jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery dual listbox plugin (http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/). I would like to add jquery validation.
If you submit the form without having selected at least one value a message should appear. When you use a normal select tag the name of the field is always submitted, if you leave the dual listbox empty the fieldname is not posted.

I have already asked this question at the developer but still got no answer.
Can someone give me a clue? Thanks.

Comment: Could you find a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Might be a bit late, but for future reference: Appending "_helper2" to the original multiselect's name did the trick for me, i.e. an error message was displayed below the target select box (the right hand one). In my case it was a custom rule, i suppose it would also work with default jquery validate rules. Example code:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="inputName_select" name="inputName">
    [options]
</select>

$('#inputName_select').bootstrapDualListbox({});

$('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
        inputName_helper2: {
            myCustomRule: true
        }
    }
});
```